# I can copy or pass by value unique pointers, how is this possible?

Tags: c++, c++17

What I've read from multiple sources states that, An `unique_ptr` cannot be copied to another `unique_ptr`, passed by value to a function, or used in any C++ Standard Library algorithm that requires copies to be made. However, I can seem to be able to do all those things.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int test(int copy)
{
    std::cout << "copy:        " << copy << std::endl;
    return copy;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> uniquePtr1(new int(4));
    std::cout << "*uniquePtr1: " << *uniquePtr1 << std::endl;

    int num1 = *uniquePtr1;
    std::cout << "num1:        " << num1 << std::endl;

    int num2 = test(*uniquePtr1);
    std::cout << "num2:        " << num2 << std::endl;

    int *ptr1 = new int;
    *ptr1 = *uniquePtr1;
    std::cout << "*ptr1:       " << *ptr1 << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr<int> uniquePtr2(new int);
    *uniquePtr2 = *uniquePtr1;
    std::cout << "*uniquePtr2: " << *uniquePtr2 << std::endl;

    delete ptr2;
}
```

```
Output:
*uniquePtr1: 4
num1:        4
copy:        4
num2:        4
*ptr2:       4
*uniquePtr2: 4
```

Am I missing something? Links are also appreciated.

Comment: You haven't copied any `unique_ptr`s--you're copying the value they point at.

Comment: See what happens if you have a `void myTest(std::unique_ptr<int> data) {}`

Comment: Does copying ```unique_ptr```'s mean, having more than one pointers point to the same memory block that ```unique_ptr``` in question points at?

Comment: ***Does copying unique_ptr's mean, having more than one pointers point to the same memory block that unique_ptr in question points at?*** No it does not.

Comment: To be clear - your program here never attempts to make a copy of a `std::unique_ptr`.  Your program has two `unique_ptr`s, and neither one is a copy of the other.

Comment: You can't _copy_ a `unique_ptr`, but you can _move_ them. So in particular "_cannot be [...] passed by value to a function,_" is generally wrong. You just have to move them into the function. And most standard library algorithms don't require copies to be made, being movable and swappable is often enough.

Comment: My understanding of "copying a ```std::unique_ptr```" seems to be inaccurate I'm trying to figure out what it is.

Comment: `auto copy = uniquePtr1;` would be an example of attempting to copy one of your `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: @nyms1 `std::unique_ptr<int> uniquePtr2 = uniquePtr1;` would be trying to copy `uniquePtr1` to `uniquePtr2` and will fail to compile. (But `std::unique_ptr<int> uniquePtr2 = std::move(uniquePtr1);` would be fine and afterwards `uniquePtr1` would be empty, not managing any object.)

Comment: `*uniquePtr1` dereferences the (unique) pointer which has the same effect as if you were using this operator for a raw pointer. The result of this expression is a reference to an `int`, i.e. `int&`. You can read or write given this reference. Your copy is a copy of the value the reference refers to. You could replace `int` with a custom type printing a message from the copy constructor/ copy assignment operator, if you want to verify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed can't copy a unique pointer, this won't compile:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> uniquePtr1(new int(4));
std::unique_ptr<int> uniquePtr2(uniquePtr1);
```

You'd need to move `uniquePtr1` into `uniquePtr2`:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> uniquePtr2(std::move(uniquePtr1));
```

What your code is doing is copying the value pointed to by the pointer.

A useful analogy would be a pointer being equivalent to a box and the value of that pointer being a ball in the box. A unique box can't hold the same ball as any other box but it is possible to look at the ball in the first unique box and add a ball of the same colour to another unique box. You now have two unique boxes, both containing red balls but not the same red ball. If you were now to paint one of the balls blue the other ball would still be red.

Expanding this analogy to shared pointers (or bare pointers) requires some balls that can exist in multiple places at the same time. With a shared box you can have the same ball in two different shared boxes and painting one ball will also change the colour of the ball in the other box.

Back to code:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> uniquePtr1(new int(4));
std::cout << *uniquePtr1; // 4
std::unique_ptr<int> uniquePtr2(new int(*uniquePtr1));
std::cout << *uniquePtr1; // 4
std::cout << *uniquePtr2; // 4
*uniquePtr1 = 5;
std::cout << *uniquePtr1; // 5
std::cout << *uniquePtr2; // still 4
```

Though `uniquePtr1` point to `int`s with the same *value* they are separate objects and updating one doesn't update the other.

With shared pointers we can copy the pointer rather than the value:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sharedPtr1(new int(4));
std::cout << *sharedPtr1; // 4
std::shared_ptr<int> sharedPtr2(new int(*sharedPtr1)); // copy the value into a new pointer
std::shared_ptr<int> sharedPtr3(sharedPtr1); // copy the pointer
std::cout << *sharedPtr1; // 4
std::cout << *sharedPtr2; // 4
std::cout << *sharedPtr3; // 4
*sharedPtr1= 5;
std::cout << *sharedPtr1; // 5
std::cout << *sharedPtr2; // still 4
std::cout << *sharedPtr3; // 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  I think I understand now but I still don't exactly understand what "copying" in this case is (I know it's not copying the value in the memory block that the pointers point at) in the second example does ```sharedPtr3``` and the ```sharedPtr1``` point at the same address, therefore it's copying?

Comment: yes, `sharedPtr3` and `sharedPtr1` are pointing at the same object, the pointer has been copied, not the value of the object the pointer is pointing to

Answer (score 1):

You haven't copied any `unique_ptr`, you're just coping the value it's pointing to.

Try these:

```
/// (1)
void f(unique_ptr<int>);

unique_ptr<int> p = make_unique(1);
f(p);

/// (2)
unique_ptr<int> p = make_unique(2);
unique_ptr<int> q = p;
```

The confusion seems to be on what it means to copy, rather than any specific confusion with `unique_ptr`.